# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when calling VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()

Tags: c#, wpf, visualtreehelper

From time to time I'm running into an **`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`** when calling `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()`.

The exception mentions not to call that method when `VisualChildrenCount` equals 0 - which is what the `if` right before the call supposedly does.

Am I missing something obvious here? I also tried to access **`contentPresenter.VisualChildrenCount`** but that property is protected.

[image: Code with AregumentOutOfRangeException.]

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted - the old code was obviously wrong but at the same time this is easy to misunderstand. The exception, after all, says "VisualChildrenCount" and not  GetChildrenCount()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetChild` method will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the child with the given index does not exist. The exception message refers to the [`VisualChildrenCount` property of the `Visual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.visualchildrencount?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Media_Visual_VisualChildrenCount) that you passed in. This property is `protected` as you have already noticed.

However, you can use the [`GetChildrenCount` on `VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchildrencount?view=net-5.0) instead. This method will access the aforementioned `VisualChildrenCount` property of the passed in `Visual` internally.

```
if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(contentPresenter) > 0)
{
   if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0) is UIElement contentVisual)
   {
      // ...your code.
   }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, that makes total sense - I imagined smth like that already but was not sure how to access it. Thanks